# After pull from git remote, Working Copy is flooded with file changes - why? Is it safe to commit them?

Tags: git, repository, atlassian-sourcetree, working-copy

This morning my employee came in and made an update to a page, then he went into SourceTree and did a pull from remote, and now he's got 62 files to be changed in his Working Copy, which appears to be all the files that I changed after hours on Friday.

Why are these appearing in his Working Copy, and is it safe for him to commit them? I had committed and pushed them, so the expectation was that when he did his pull, he'd be synced with everything I had done without having to do this large commit as if he himself has performed these changes.

Feedback?

edit (more info): We're both brand new to a git workflow... we rolled it out last week after practicing on a development server for a couple weeks.

Comment: was it a merge conflict?

Comment: Yes. But it's not *really* a conflict... it's all the changes I already pushed last week. e.g. new files that I created, it now has in his Working Copy as though he's created them and needs to push them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge conflict might occur due to several reasons. It might be because of different versions of the same file and both the versions of the file being created after the divergence in the history.

When you say, `git status`, you should be able to see unmerged paths in your repository. You need to fix them. [Here's a fine article on resolving merge conflicts.](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/)

After you have fixed the files. You just need to add and commit:

```
git add -A
git commit
```